# how to make a PowerUP duration timer resets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have two different timed Power-Ups in my project, both with 5 seconds duration. I'd like to make that if I pick a Power Up before the time ends, It makes the timer counts again from zero, but it is not happening. If I pick up the same Power UP while remaining 1 second, it lasts just for one second instead of 5. I'm using in the Player Script a public void that is called out by the Power UP when it is picked up

My Player's code:

```
public void TripleShotActive()
{        
    _canTripleShot = true;
    StopCoroutine(TripleShotPowerDownRoutine());
    StartCoroutine(TripleShotPowerDownRoutine());
    return;

}

public void SpeedBoostPowerupActive()
{        
    _speedBoostActive = true;
    StopCoroutine(SpeedBoostPowerDownRoutine());
    StartCoroutine(SpeedBoostPowerDownRoutine());
    return;
}

public void ShieldsActive()
{
    _isShieldsActive = true;
    _shieldVisualizer.SetActive(true);
}


IEnumerator TripleShotPowerDownRoutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
    _canTripleShot = false;
}

IEnumerator SpeedBoostPowerDownRoutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
    _speedBoostActive = false;
}
```

I tried using StopCoroutine before StartCoroutine, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the coroutine earlier created by StartCoroutine.

```
Coroutine _tripleShotPowerDown;

public void TripleShotActive()
{        
    _canTripleShot = true;
    if(_tripleShotPowerDown != null)
        StopCoroutine(_tripleShotPowerDown);
    _tripleShotPowerDown = StartCoroutine(TripleShotPowerDownRoutine());
    return;
}
```

Comment: If I got it right, _tripleShotPowerDown only will be null if I haven't picked the Power UP yet, right?
But I don't understand why I must declare "Coroutine _tripleShotPowerDown;" in order to work, I mean, I'm already using StopCoroutine

Comment: If you don't declare one, what you decide to pass to StopCoroutine? In your OP you passed `TripleShotPowerDownRoutine()`, now just think about it, how could StopCoroutine correspond this `TripleShotPowerDownRoutine()` to that `TripleShotPowerDownRoutine()`? Note that everytime you call `TripleShotPowerDownRoutine` it returns a new instance.

Comment: Oooooh, I got. I pretty new to coding,m but it really makes sense to me now, thank you. But I just don't get: When we declare 
   _tripleShotPowerDown = StartCoroutine(TripleShotPowerDownRoutine());

It assigns _tripleshotPowerDown and at the same time Start the Coroutine?

Comment: Start first, assign next.

Comment: Cool, I didn't new the code could work like that, cause we are assigning and starting at the same line of code